# @Published ObservableObject not updating SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I am working on SwiftUI and displaying MapView using UIViewRepresentable.
Now, when map is loaded then I am calculating route between two points and i am storing that route in model.

```
class MapInfo: ObservableObject {
    @Published var routeArray: [RouteArray] = []
}
```

I am calling the calculateRoute() function in UIViewRepresentable MapCoordinator

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @StateObject var mapInfo = MapInfo()
}

func requestRoute() {
    // when response is received 
    parentView.mapView.mapInfo.routeArray = responseArray
}
```

But My problem is SwiftUI View onReceive is not getting called when MapInfo @Published RouteArray is updated.

I have added my code.

```
struct MapContainerView: View {
      @ObservedObject var mapInfoObj = MapInfo()
      
      var body: some View {
          ZStack {
             MapView()
          }.onReceive(mapInfoObj.$routeArray) { updatedRouteArray in
             print(updatedRouteArray)
          }
      }

}
```

Any help with this is highly appreciated.
Thank you :)

Comment: You have two different `MapInfo` instances. You need to pass the one from your `MapContainerView` to your `MapView` via its initialiser.

Comment: yes, you are right @Paulw11. My bad!! I missed this basic thing. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

As @Paulw11 mentioned in the comments, you are using different instances of `MapInfo` which simply means, updating one instance does not update the other one since they are different.

To solve this, your need to create only one instance of your `MapInfo` in your `MapContainerView` and then pass it to your `MapContainerView` view so both views can share the same data and get updated when the data changes.

Your code would look like:

#### 1. MapView

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @ObservedObject var mapInfo: MapInfo
}

func requestRoute() {
    // when response is received 
    parentView.mapView.mapInfo.routeArray = responseArray
}
```

#### 2. MapContainerView

```
struct MapContainerView: View {
      @StateObject var mapInfoObj = MapInfo()
      
      var body: some View {
          ZStack {
             // Here now, the two views are sharing the same data
             MapView(mapInfo: mapInfoObj)
          }.onReceive(mapInfoObj.$routeArray) { updatedRouteArray in
             print(updatedRouteArray)
          }
      }

}
```

Comment: yes, you are right @cedricbahirwe. My bad!! I missed this basic thing. Thank you :)

Comment: The pleasure is all mine

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, I missed to share the variable across different view.

```
struct MapContainerView: View {
  @StateObject var mapInfoObj = MapInfo()
  
  var body: some View {
      ZStack {
         // Here now, the two views are sharing the same data
         MapView(mapInfo: mapInfoObj)
      }.onReceive(mapInfoObj.$routeArray) { updatedRouteArray in
         print(updatedRouteArray)
      }
   }
  }
```